# Encoding JSON in a GitHub Pages generated file

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm attempting to create a JSON feed on a GitHub Pages site, and I'm having issues with JSON because I'm not sure how I can properly encode it using Jekyll. Is there an extension or method I can use?

feed: http://iowacodecamp.github.io/sessions.json

source: https://github.com/IowaCodeCamp/iowacodecamp.github.io/blob/master/sessions.json

Note the double quotes in the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your json doesn't validate because of the coma after the last session.

If you don't want a coma after the last session, use [forloop liquid object](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops) around

```
{
  "sessions": {
    "session": [{% for session_hash in site.data.sessions %}{% assign session = session_hash[1] %}
       {
          "title": {{ session.title | jsonify }},
          "description": {{ session.description | jsonify }},
          "level": {{ session.level | jsonify }},
          "author": {
              "name": {{ session.speaker.name | jsonify }},
              "slug": {{ session.speaker.slug | jsonify }}
          }
       }{% if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
    ]
  }
}
```

Question : You have multiples sessions in your datas but they are all in the same **session** array. Do you really need this key ? Maybe you can just do :

```
{
  "sessions": [{% for session in site.data.sessions %}
       {{ session[1] | jsonify }}{% if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
  ]
}
```

Which also [validates](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the 2 tips. I implemented both of them.

Comment: Cool. Can approve the answer please ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a list of filters in the documentation: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

Proper usage is:

```
{{ session.description | jsonify }}
```